# Validation for jquery ui dialog box popups

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

Are there any techniques/best practices for validation user input when using a jquery-ui dialog box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already in your demo pacakage from jquery website. Check form-model in dialog demo.

Or you can look [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-form-dialog-submiting-to-coldfusion-page-nothing-happens).